# Is it natural to say "I hit him by surprise" or "I sneakily hit him"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is it natural to say "**I hit him by surprise**" or "**I sneakily hit him**" to mean we sneakily hit somebody and he didn't know it at first and to make him surprised?

Some people suggest "**I sneaked up on him and hit him**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I hit him by surprise" would be fairly natural, or "I sucker-punched him." but not "I sneakily hit him”" (the last might be "I hit him from ambush" or "I snuck up and hit him from behind")